# What are the best practices for migrating an existing Sinatra app (+datamapper) to Rails 3 (+active record)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, sinatra, datamapper

When migrating an existing web application built using Sinatra and Datamapper, how would one go about migrating it to a Ruby on Rails (v3.1) and ActiveRecord application?

For example, start by migrating to ActiveRecord first while still using Sinatra. Once completed, move to controllers, etc. Or perhaps the other way around, start with migrating the controllers and continue using Datamapper at first.

I don't think it's a good idea to actually run the partly migrated code in a production environment, but I do like to migrate in a structured way so I can solve one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't migrate from DataMapper to ActiveRecord, that is counterproductive. The level of abstraction of DataMapper is way higher than the ActiveRecord's.

However, jumping to Rails you may find lots of sugar using very nice plugins or gems not known for friendship with Sinatra.

Try searching for gems that claims framework agnostic support and depends on just Rack and/or ActiveModel, not Rails.

Comment: I like Datamapper too, but your statement is speculation.

Comment: I ended up just rewriting the functionality as similar as possible and then recreating the Datamapper database structure and used Rails' migrations to change it to my final structure (since it wasn't exactly the same as before.)